# gzip - no such file or directory found

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install a piece of software from the University of Strathclyde using WSL with Ubuntu 18.04.3. The software comes in a pre-compiled installer, a .gz file.

When I run this command:

```
gzip -d (file name).deb.gz
```

I get the following error:

```
No such file or directory
```

However, I can see the file on my Windows Downloads folder. Does anybody know how to overcome this?

Comment: Does the filename contain special characters such as `*` or whitespaces?

Comment: The shell will expect the file to be in its *current working directory* - it doesn't know anything about a "Windows Downloads" folder

Answer (score 1):

if filename have space use your command with quotes:

```
gzip -d "file name.deb.gz"
```

and make sure you are in current dirrectory with this file:

```
ls . | grep "file name.deb.gz"
```